How to call an R function conditional on a printed string?
I'm using the tesseract package to mine text from a very large (>500K) set of scanned documents. Some of the documents are rotated the wrong way, so when I call tesseract::ocr on those, the following text usually appears on the console:
Image too small to scale!! (2x36 vs min width of 3)
Line cannot be recognized!!

My solution is to write a function that will try rotating the document when that message pops up. Unfortunately I've learned from the source code that this text is produced using tprintf -- that is, it's not an error/warning/message so an error-handling operation like withCallingHandlers doesn't work. And the underlying conditional statement that produces this text is inscrutable to me (here's the source code; see lines 329-332).
So I'm wondering: Is it possible to call a function conditional on certain text merely being printed on the console?
(Alternatively, if you have an different way to solve this issue that doesn't require responding to the printed text, I'm all ears.)

Here's a simple example we can play with. Let's say we wanted to write a function that will be called when test prints "Do something!" but not when it prints anything else.
test <- function(i) {
  switch(i, "1"=print("Do nothing!"), "2"= print("Do something!"), i)
}

> test(1)
[1] "Do nothing!"

> test(2)
[1] "Do something."

> test(3)
[1] 3


use capture.output to capture the printed text, then use conditions

Oh, that's perfect! Thank you!
